# getting empty array on express response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working on an example, I am trying to get a single employee instance from this express example, but when I type, localhost:3000/1, I am getting an empty array. does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

```js
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const app = express();

var employees = [
 {
   "EmployeeID" :1 ,
   "EmployeeName" : "RNA Team",
   "Salary" : "200000",
   "Address" : "Bangalore"
   },
   {
   "EmployeeID" :2 ,
   "EmployeeName" : "Mahesh Samabesh",
   "Salary" : "100000",
   "Address" : "Hydrabad"
   },
   {
   "EmployeeID" :3 ,
   "EmployeeName" : "Rui Figo",
   "Salary" : "50000",
   "Address" : "Dallas"
   },
   {
   "EmployeeID" :4 ,
   "EmployeeName" : "Indradev Jana",
   "Salary" : "456789",
   "Address" : "Los Angles"
   },
   {
   "EmployeeID" :5 ,
   "EmployeeName" : "Suresh Shailesh",
   "Salary" : "1234567",
   "Address" : "Patna"
  }
];

//Get the employees records

app.get('/', function(req, res){
 res.send(employees);
});

//run the server
var server = app.listen(3000, function(){
 var host = server.address().address;
 var port  = server.address().port;

 console.log('Server started and listening at:> http://%s:%s', host, port);
});

//Get single employee record
app.get('/:EmployeeID', function(req, res){
 var employeeID = req.params.EmployeeID;

 //Get Employee Records whose EmployeeID = get the EmployeeID at runtime
 var filteredEmployee = [];

 for(var i=0; i < employees.length; i++){
  if(employees[i].EmployeeID == employeeID){
   filteredEmployee.push(employees[i]);
  }
 } //end Loop
 employees = filteredEmployee;
 console.log(filteredEmployee);
 res.send(employees);
});
```

Comment: What is `req.params.EmployeeID` when you try it?  One possibility here is that you aren't passing in the right ID so thus you never find a match.  Also, you should not be changing the `employees` array just because you're searching it.  That will damage the data for the next time you want to search it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're re-assigning your employees object.

```
employees = filteredEmployee;
```

will set your employees object to be the single found employee. So it will work the first time, and it does. Then any subsequent tries it will only have a single employee in it.

You just want to do `res.send(filteredEmployee)` after your loop.

also your code is picking up your browsers request to `/favicon.ico` as an employee param.

adding this will block that:

```
 app.get('/favicon.ico', function(req, res) {
     res.send(204);
 });
```

Fixed example:

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const app = express();

var employees = [
    {
   "EmployeeID" :1 ,
   "EmployeeName" : "RNA Team",
   "Salary" : "200000",
   "Address" : "Bangalore"
   },
   {
   "EmployeeID" :2 ,
   "EmployeeName" : "Mahesh Samabesh",
   "Salary" : "100000",
   "Address" : "Hydrabad"
   },
   {
   "EmployeeID" :3 ,
   "EmployeeName" : "Rui Figo",
   "Salary" : "50000",
   "Address" : "Dallas"
   },
   {
   "EmployeeID" :4 ,
   "EmployeeName" : "Indradev Jana",
   "Salary" : "456789",
   "Address" : "Los Angles"
   },
   {
   "EmployeeID" :5 ,
   "EmployeeName" : "Suresh Shailesh",
   "Salary" : "1234567",
   "Address" : "Patna"
  }
];

//Get the employees records

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send(employees);
});

//run the server
var server = app.listen(3000, function(){
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port  = server.address().port;

    console.log('Server started and listening at:> http://%s:%s', host, port);
});

app.get('/favicon.ico', function(req, res) {
    res.send(204);
});

//Get single employee record
app.get('/:employeeID', function(req, res){
    var employeeID = req.params.employeeID;

    //Get Employee Records whose EmployeeID = get the EmployeeID at runtime
    var filteredEmployee = [];

    for(var i=0; i < employees.length; i++){
        if(employees[i].EmployeeID == employeeID){
            filteredEmployee.push(employees[i]);
        }
    } //end Loop
    console.log(filteredEmployee);
    res.send(filteredEmployee);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You really shouldn't mutate your data in a query operation. You could do something like this:

```
app.get('/:EmployeeID', (req, res) => {
  const employeeID = req.params.EmployeeID;
  // filter the employees without mutating the array, and get the first result
  const [employee] = employees.filter(e => e.EmployeeID === employeeID)
  // if there was a result, send it, otherwise send an error
  res.json(employee ? employee : { error: `Employee with id ${employeeID} not found` })
});
```

Comment: Thanks Balazs, I tried to get this to work, but not sure, what I did wrong here. Am I able to set an array as a const in ES5? or that is just a placeholder?

Answer (score 1):

You are actually mutating your data. The way you are doing will work only for once and then your employee array will change. So just remove `employees = filteredEmployee;` and directly send `res.send(filteredEmployee);` instead.

Comment: Why would this fix anything?